# How do I modify my JS code to work with my new URL structure?

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to extract a search string from a URL.

I'm able to do it when the URL looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/search/keyword
```

but not when the URL looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/#/search/keyword
```

The following is the Javascript code that worked for my first example, except I can't get it to work now that the URL structure has changed.

```
function () {
  // find and store the path of the current page
  var pagePath = location.pathname;
  // if the path starts with /search/, we know it's an internal SERP
  if (pagePath.indexOf("/search/") === 0) {
    // if the above checks out, let's figure out where the search term begins in the URL. Then, let's use that starting point to pull out the search term itself.
    var searchString = pagePath.substring(pagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    // return what we found to GTM as the value of our variable
    return searchString;
  }
  // if it's not an internal SERP page, return "none"
  else {
    return "none";
  }
}
```

The code above works just fine when the URL structure looks like this:

http://domain.com/search/keyword

but not when it looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/#/search/keyword
```

The question is: how do I modify my JS code above to work with my new URL structure?

I've tried changing the part of my JS code from:

```
  if (pagePath.indexOf("/search/") === 0) {
```

to

```
  if (pagePath.indexOf("/#/search/") === 0) {
```

but I can't get it work. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

The hash symbol `#` denotes a [url fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and is not part of the `pathname`. You can access the url fragment using `location.hash`